# K3s Allow Unauthenticated Access to OIDC Endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, k3s

**Goal**

I want to allow unauthenticated access to the following OIDC endpoints in my K3s cluster (from other pods inside the cluster mostly but access from outside is also acceptable):

- https://kubernetes.default.svc/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://kubernetes.default.svc/openid/v1/jwks

**Problem**

By default, Kubernetes requires an authorization token for accessing those endpoints and despite my efforts to enable unauthenticated access, I cannot seem to get the unauthenticated access to work.

**What I have tried**

According to the Kubernetes documentation on [Service account issuer discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-issuer-discovery), one must create a ClusterRoleBinding that maps the ClusterRole `system:service-account-issuer-discovery` to the Group `system:unauthenticated`.

I also found this helpful example for a different use-case but they're exposing the OIDC endpoints anonymously just like I want to do:
[OIDC issuer discovery for Kubernetes service accounts](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/kubernetes-oidc/)

Based on both of those, I created my ClusterRoleBinding with:

```bash
kubectl create clusterrolebinding service-account-issuer-discovery-unauthenticated --clusterrole=system:service-account-issuer-discovery --group=system:unauthenticated
```

This results in the following spec:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-28T15:24:41Z"
  name: service-account-issuer-discovery-unauthenticated
  resourceVersion: "92377634"
  uid: 75402324-a8cf-412f-923e-a7a87ed082c2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:service-account-issuer-discovery
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: system:unauthenticated
```

I also confirmed RBAC is enabled by running this which showed an entry:

```bash
kubectl api-versions | grep 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1'
```

Unfortunately, despite creating that ClusterRoleBinding, it still seems to be requiring an authorization token to access the OIDC endpoints. For example, when I call from outside the cluster:

```bash
curl -vk https://my-cluster-hostname:6443/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Output:

```json
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

Accessing from the Ingress controller inside the pod (by execing into it), I get the same error.

```bash
curl -vk https://kubernetes.default.svc/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

I am using K3s for this cluster... Is there something special about K3s that I have not accounted for? Do I need to do something to get this ClusterRoleBinding to take effect? Something else I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the `--anonymous-auth` api server setting is set to `false` by default.

I was able to adjust this with my already-installed K3s server nodes by editing the systemd unit for the k3s service. Step-by-step guide:

Edit the systemd unit with:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service
```

You'll see the K3s unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lightweight Kubernetes
Documentation=https://k3s.io
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/%N
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/%N
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service.env
KillMode=process
Delegate=yes
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -xc '! /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service'
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe br_netfilter
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe overlay
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--cluster-init' \
        '--disable=traefik' \
        '--write-kubeconfig-mode' \
        '644' \
```

Add the last two lines to the `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--cluster-init' \
        '--disable=traefik' \
        '--write-kubeconfig-mode' \
        '644' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' \
        '--anonymous-auth=true' \
```

Reload the systemd unit:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally, restart the k3s service:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart k3s
```

References:

- [Control Plane Execution and Arguments](https://docs.k3s.io/security/hardening-guide#control-plane-execution-and-arguments) - You can see the default for K3s there
- [API discovery roles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#discovery-roles) - also mentions this flag at the top